# Zoom in plot when we have multiple plots and have used show function

Tags: plotting

I have a plot that I made with the help of the show function.
But I need to zoom in on this plot I tried once but it is not enough I need to zoom until I see the difference between gray dots green line and red line but unfortunately I can not do it is there any idea how to do it?
p1 p2 p4 p5 are plots of some results!

```
 p8 = Show[{p1, p2, p4, p5}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"E_Steel/E_Rubber", "U"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
  Axes -> False, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  PlotRange -> {{5, 10}, {0.75, 4}}, ImageSize -> 1000]
Export["EnergieZoomed.png", p8]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is not complete.

Comment: Thank you! Already edited.

Comment: Please post your code about `p1,p2,p3,p4`.

Comment: The whole Code in wolfarmcloud

Comment: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/2aa28383-9a51-4ac9-894e-563dd1226e87

Comment: wolframcloud.com/obj/2aa28383-9a51-4ac9-894e-563dd1226e87 @cvgmt

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information. Use the comments section only for discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all your p1 is not clear in graph despite i used Magnification.**

**So edit your p1 to be like this. you still can make Style no Thick**

```
p1 = ListLogLogPlot[UvaluesAgainstYSteeltoYRubber, 
  AxesLabel -> {"E_Steel/e_Rubber", "U"}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
     Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"compound model Ritz"}]
```

**Now as you see that in p8 Show, its there !!!**

[image]

**Now go ahead use little value of Magnify**

```
Magnify[p8, 5]
```

[image]

***Actually your Data and Curves are truly fitted on each other. Its means you are so pro in what ever experiment is this !***

Comment: @ Ali AlCapone  I think thats the solution to your problem.
Just edit p1 and you are good to show red marks and line clearly

Comment: Thank you Very much. :D

Comment: @ Ali AlCapone 
you still can play around with plot range and magnify. 
but truly man your curves are fitted. 
Dont bother your self anymore.
Enough to show this part and thats it

Comment: I see, thank you very much ;) Respect also for your programming talent